# Is this grammar left recursive or factor?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, left-recursion

I am new to this topic of left recursion and left factoring, please help me in determining whether this grammar is left recursive or left factored, if it is then why ?

S-> aAd | bBd | aBe | bAe | cA | cB

Comment: Do you have a guess? :)

Comment: @summea i have a guess that there is no left recursion but doubt about left factoring. But seeing it there is no production of non-terminals A and B which in my point of view also not left factored, but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is it Left recursive? Answer: No.**

By definition, "A grammar is left-recursive if we can find some non-terminal A which will eventually derive a sentential form with itself as the left-symbol."

example: 
Immediate left recursion occurs in rules of the form

```
A -> Aa | b
```

where **a** and **b** are sequences of nonterminals and terminals, and **b** doesn't start with **A**.

Clearly not the case in:

S-> aAd | bBd | aBe | bAe | cA | cB

**Is it Left factored?  Answer: Yes.**

By definition, in left factoring, it is not clear which two alternative production to choose, to expand a non-terminal.

This ambiguity occurs, when you have two alternative production that starts with same terminal/non-terminal. 
In your case, I can see that thrice, two alternative paths:

```
S-> aAd | aBe 

S-> bBd |  bAe 

S-> cA | cB
```

If I remove the left factoring then the grammar becomes:

```
S-> aA'

A'-> Ad | Be

S-> bB'

B'-> Bd | Ae

S-> cC'

C'-> A | B
```

This [slide](http://www.slideshare.net/hussiensharaf/cs419-lec10-left-recursion-and-left-factoring) explains the same in simpler words

Comment: And the solution for this is: S-> aAd | aBe = (S-> aS') ; (S'->Ad|Be) and for all the others ?

Comment: pretty much, provided production of A & B creates no further ambiguity.

Comment: I am very pleased from your kind reply, this small point has cleared my 4 to 5 lectures on compiler construction. I am very thankful to you, your are a great person.